# Why do I get different results in getelement methods when using get method and ie.navigate?

Tags: vba, msxml, mshtml, shdocvw.internetexplorer

I have been looking for the answer on this question for quite some time. Below here i have two parts of code that load html of a website into memory. Same result. But de getelements methods, for example getelementsbyclassname do not work when i use the 'Get' method. I wanted to use the quicker 'Get' method but due to this different outcome I couldn't. In the first line of code getElementsByClassName works, but in the second part its outcome remains nothing.

I really couldn't figure out why, I have been stuck for some time now. I hope here you can help met out. Thank you in advance.

```
<i>Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim URL As String
Dim Element1 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement, Element2 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement, 
Element3 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim Elementen As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

URL = "https://www.google.nl/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=KXNcWsHNJ9OB4gTcjqvwCA"

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate URL

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
Set Element1 = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("gsfi")(0)
Set Element2 = HTMLDoc.getElementById("lst-ib")
Debug.Print Element1.className, Element2.className


Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim URL As String
Dim Element1 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim Element2 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

URL = "https://www.google.nl/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=KXNcWsHNJ9OB4gTcjqvwCA"

XMLPage.Open "Get", URL, False
XMLPage.send

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

Set Element1 = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("gsfi")(0)
Set Element2 = HTMLDoc.getElementById("lst-ib")
Debug.Print Element2.className</i>
```

Comment: And I of course activated the libraries Microsoft XML, Microsoft HTML Object Library and Microsoft Internet Controls.

Comment: What does this have to do with Excel? You could ask the same question from within Word, Access, Powerpoint, or even using VBScript.

Comment: I just tagged excel because I always execute these codes from excel. But I see tag excel already had been removed.

Comment: Why do you want to know that? What you wanna achieve actually? I suppose you were getting bored so thought to post a question, ain't it? FYI, the site you have mentioned in your script is javascript encrypted. When you deal with any site containing stuffs generated dynamically, the results producing from two different requests will never be the same. Hope you got it.